# How to make flow_from_directory color_mode cannot change input size

Tags: python, keras

My img are 5 * 1channel, 1 * 3 channels, I concatenate them and save to .npy be a 18 channels file.

Mask are 6 * 1channel, but when 1 channel cannot do concatenate on axis=2 so they are 18 channels file too.

but when I training, appear this error messsage. I modify image_color_mode to rgba,got array with shape be (512, 512, 4). I think problem at here.

How to make color_mode cannot modify input shape?

```
error message
發生例外狀況: ValueError
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (512, 512, 18) but got array with shape (512, 512, 3)
  File "C:\Labbb\testing\unet_mao0\main.py", line 96, in <module>
    train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=30,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (512, 512, 18) but got array with shape (512, 512, 3)
```

```
def trainGenerator(batch_size, train_path, image_folder, mask_folder, aug_dict,image_color_mode='rgb', mask_color_mode='rgb', 
                   image_save_prefix="image", mask_save_prefix="mask", 
                   flag_multi_class=False, num_class=7, save_to_dir=None, target_size=(512, 512), seed=1, file_extension=".npy"):

    
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        classes = image_folder,
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = image_color_mode,
        target_size = target_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
        save_prefix  = image_save_prefix,
        seed = seed)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        classes = mask_folder,
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = mask_color_mode,
        target_size = target_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
        save_prefix  = mask_save_prefix,
        seed = seed)
```

Comment: ImageDataGenerator does not support  18 channel images, only RGB or grayscale.